# Valid characters for actions, hooks and filters

Tags: filters, hooks, actions

I haven't ever seen a tag such as `do_action('something_10')`. Is it invalid if I use numbers?

If the method is valid, how can I write different numbers in the tag string conditionally? For example, is the following code correct($grade is the number)?

```
do_action("new_grade_$grade")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. When you "hook"/`add_action/*_filter('whatever');` a callback function to `do_action('whatever');`, then you basically add the function (or object-method) name to the `global $wp_filters`-array.
2. Doing so, you add the function/method name to an array that is built like the following

   ```
   $wp_filter[ $tag ][ $priority ][ $idx ]
   // $tag = action/filter name
   // $priority = 3rd argument / execution order
   // $idx = "unique" name
   ```
3. Not the 3rd argument/`$idx` is built using the `_wp_filter_build_unique_id()` function, that takes the first args from `add_action/*_filter()`.
4. Inside this function, every function name stays the same, only method names change. This is the reason, why you often find "funky" method names, prefixed with a pretty long number.

> Can I add numbers after letters in do_action tag?

So yes, numbers are completely valid when naming action hooks. Summed up, it's save to use `a-zA-Z0-9_` as function/method/variable names. `-` is not supported. And while some characters might work well on your system, it mostly depends on the encoding if your chosen function name (example: `_wUT?a_nice_DÄY!()`) works or not. WordPress itself does not check if a function/var/hook/filter/whatever name is valid or not.

---

*Addition to @BrianFegter answer about "contextual hooks".*

You can see some "contextual hooks", when you take a look at the »help«-panel in (any) screen in your (MU or single) installation, using [this plugin](https://gist.github.com/3711215)<sup>1)</sup>.

[image]
[image]

<sup>1) Plugin inspired by @StephenHarris article.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can dynamically create your own action hooks. WordPress has several dynamic hooks like `admin_head-hookname` and `admin_footer-hookname`. `new_grade_$n` is a valid hook name.

Comment: Thanks! Then, should I use "_$n" or "-$n" ?

Comment: @Jenny Whatever your preference is. :)